# how to visualize images after dense layer in cnn model in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

My CNN model contains convolution layer and dense layers. I am able to visualize images and filter of convolution layers with help of below code, but unable to see output images after dense layers (only images, because there is no filters). When i tried using below code i am getting error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-25-e8e4d4494672>", line 35, in <module>
    num_of_featuremaps=feature_maps.shape[2]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
#and after that some blank space
```

code is following:

```
def get_featuremaps(model, layer_idx, X_batch):
    get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],[model.layers[layer_idx].output,])
    activations = get_activations([X_batch,0])
    return activations

layer_num=11
filter_num=0
test_image=x[0]
test_image_show=test_image[:,:,0]
plt.axis('off')
test_image= np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
print (test_image.shape)
activations = get_featuremaps(model, int(layer_num),test_image)

print (np.shape(activations))
feature_maps = activations[0][0]      
print (np.shape(feature_maps))

if K.image_dim_ordering()=='th':
    feature_maps=np.rollaxis((np.rollaxis(feature_maps,2,0)),2,0)

print (feature_maps.shape)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
#plt.imshow(feature_maps[:,:,filter_num],cmap='gray')

#plt.savefig("featuremaps-layer-{}".format(layer_num) + "-filternum-{}".format(filter_num)+'.jpg')

num_of_featuremaps=feature_maps.shape[2]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,16)) 
plt.title("featuremaps-layer-{}".format(layer_num))
subplot_num=int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(num_of_featuremaps)))
for i in range(int(num_of_featuremaps)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(subplot_num, subplot_num, i+1)
    ax.imshow(feature_maps[:,:,i],cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
def nice_imshow(ax, data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None):
    """Wrapper around pl.imshow"""
    if cmap is None:
        cmap = cm.jet
    if vmin is None:
        vmin = data.min()
    if vmax is None:
        vmax = data.max()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    pl.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

model looks like following:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_37 (Conv2D)           (None, 49, 49, 32)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_38 (Conv2D)           (None, 48, 48, 32)        4128      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_19 (MaxPooling (None, 24, 24, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_28 (Dropout)         (None, 24, 24, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_39 (Conv2D)           (None, 23, 23, 64)        8256      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_40 (Conv2D)           (None, 22, 22, 64)        16448     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling (None, 11, 11, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)         (None, 11, 11, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_10 (Flatten)         (None, 7744)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 256)               1982720   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_30 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 514       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,012,226
Trainable params: 2,012,226
Non-trainable params: 0
_____________________________________
```

where pl is pylab and plt is matplotlib.

Comment: Well.... you simply don't have anything near images after the flatten layers.

Comment: yes i know, because flatten makes a array from matrix. But is there any way to transform them back to matrix form. I want to see them as images because though there are no filters in dense layers but, weight is changes over there and we are using activations also

Comment: You can use "reshape" (numpy) after you get the activations. But this doesn't make sense. **Luckily** your dense layers have 256 neurons, so you can reshape with (-1,16,16,1), you could have a prime number there and there wouldn't be anything to do except to look at a horizontal strip.

Comment: yes you are correct, it's strip only